# ember redirect mirage requests to another route in imported module

Tags: ember.js

my ember app has an adapter which generates below URL when I query for all employee models:

/proxy/v1/employees/details (namespace i have defined is /proxy/v1)

I am importing one node module which is an another ember app that has a route defined in mirage as: /employee/details

Is there a way my main app can call this route? Currently mirage throws me an error saying that route: /proxy/v1/employees/details is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a separate Mirage route before you specify your namespace. It is possible to have multiple routes with different namespaces if you do that ...